# What is the best way to simultaneously display multiple views (webpages) from a single action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using MVC 5...
I have a view (webpage) that currently contains too much content. It's way too busy and hard to understand.

What I'd like is to have the action that creates the view (webpage) to create 2 views (webpages) with the current content divided between both views. And when the action gets invoked again, I need to update the content of both views. I want two separate pages, not multiple partial views on the same page (what my searching has turned up). It's important to be able to see all the content at the same time.

How many times have you opened 2 webpages and positioned them side by side on your monitor so you could compare the content. That’s what I want to do.

I know I could have an action link on the first page that displays a second page (target=_blank) but that means the user has to click the link. I don't want that. I want all the content displayed without unnecessary user intervention. I know I could embed a JavaScript window.open on the first page to open the second page, but that seems like an unnecessary hack.

Mr. Google hasn't been helpful other than to convince me I'm trying to do something that's not best practice. So I'm open to any suggestions about alternative ways to display the page content that are more in-line with MVC best practices.

Comment: At the HTML level, what's the difference between "two separate pages" and "multiple partial views on the same page"?  An action can only return one view, but that view can display whatever side-beside content you want.

Comment: So write the code for updating one view. Once you are satisfied its working fine you can take the Parent DOM element and may be `on blur` you can dynamically render the right hand side of web page. Just like Word Press web site preview works. You make changes in the left side of the screen and as soon as you focus out the preview on the right side gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem: SignalR!

From: https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr

"ASP.NET SignalR is a library for ASP.NET developers that simplifies the process of adding real-time web functionality to applications. Real-time web functionality is the ability to have server code push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes available, rather than having the server wait for a client to request new data."

My "main" page is a standard MVC view that (in my case) uses Ajax to facilitate user interaction with the page. There's an actionlink on the "main" page that optionally displays a second "details" page (target="_blank"). Once the "details" page is visible, the two windows can be placed as desired on your monitor(s).

The "details" page is updated using SignalR. It's a SignalR client. When the user posts an event on the "main" page, the associated controller action builds new content for the "main" page view. And it also broadcasts messages, using the SignalR Hub, to the "details" page.

When the controller action ends, both pages have been updated.